# ipython: access notebook server remotely via a web browser

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to access notebook server remotely via a web browser, the [following](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-python-ipython-notebook/?cdn=disable)  shows how did I setup my notebook server:

1.generate config file

```
$ jupyter-notebook --generate-config
$　cd ~/.jupyter
```

2.Use the following command to create the SSL certificate(Linux and Windows).

```
req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
```

3.edit the profile's configuration file, which is the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` the password has been generated..

```
c = get_config()

# You must give the path to the certificate file.
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/azureuser/.jupyter/mycert.pem'

# Create your own password as indicated above
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:b86e933199ad:a02e9592e5 etc... '

# Network and browser details. We use a fixed port (9999) so it matches
# our Azure setup, where we've allowed :wqtraffic on that port
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.port = 9999
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
```

4.start `$ jupyter-notebook` server

You should now be able to access your Jupyter Notebook at the address https://[PUBLIC-IP-ADDRESS]:9999.

Start notebook:

```
$  ~ jupyter-notebook 
[I 16:46:58.627 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/user
[I 16:46:58.627 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 16:46:58.627 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: https://SERVER_IP:9999/
[I 16:46:58.627 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

But, when I open my browser(at my home, the notebook server is in my lab) at https://MY_SERVER_IP:9999, the page can not be open.  And Chrome-browser returns:

```
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

What should I do?

Comment: What happens? Particularly: (A) what does the browser do? Are you getting a return code at all, connecting at all, etc? (B) Are you trying to access it from the same computer, or a different one? Is there a firewall in the way, or  are there potential routing problems? (C) Does anything show up on the command line that's unusual, either when starting or when trying to access it?

Comment: @cge, I have showed the details above.

Comment: May be bot direct answer, but I would _recommend_ when possible: 1) start jupyter service without auth & do not open port 2) From the remote site tunel with ssh -L jupyter_port & access via localhost. So you just move all auth stuff to the ssh that works & is safe

Comment: Sounds like your problem is less likely to be with Jupyter than with access to your lab machine. Are you sure port 9999 is not blocked by something? Can you ping the machines? Maybe portscan them? My lab's servers, for example, block almost everything but 22 for ssh, and we port forward with ssh as suggested by @Lol4t0. For another setup I use direct connections, but have to make sure that the ports aren't blocked by a firewall.

Comment: @cge, yes, you are right, the 9999 port has been blocked. I can ping the machine. I setup the notebook server via ssh, so the 22 port is not blocked.

Comment: @cge,And there is another apache process is running on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corresponding port `9999` is block on the server, and the server is `Centos7` and iptables is not available to open ports, so use `firewall-cmd` to active the port:

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9999/tcp --permanent
$ firewall-cmd --reload
```

If firewallD is not running, just start the service.

Answer (score 3):

Those instructions you followed are a bit dated specifically:

1. Anaconda is at version 4.
2. Jupyter comes pre-installed with new Anaconda
3. Jupyter defaults to port "8888"
4. You should mention how to get to the modifications you note for the configuration. I ended up going into nano to do it.
5. You can't use "sudo" with conda.

If you want to install Ipython notebook from scratch on a VPS, and access it via ssh I wrote an updated tutorial here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-jupyter-notebook-to-run-ipython-on-ubuntu-16-04

After installing and running Ipython Notebook using command line on the server, you can connect to the notebook using SSH tunnelling with Putty (on windows) or the `ssh -L` command on Unix-like systems (ie Mac and Linux)